# C++ class template or pure virtual

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a template class that is intended to be used both as a base for deriving and for use as a concrete class if the template parameters are right.

What I want to achieve is that if a method of the template class cannot be instantiated, but a deriving class provides an implementation, that this is OK.
But if the template can be fully instantiated that the class is valid on it's own.

Example:

```
// interface class
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~A() {}
};

// template class
template <typename T>
class B : public A
{
public:
    /* if this tenplate can be instantiated */
    foo() 
    {
        T obj;
        std::cout << obj;
    }
    /* else
    foo() = 0;
    */
};

// concrete classes
// will work on it's own
typedef B<std::string> C;

class D : public B<void>
{
    // B<void>::foo won't instantiate on it's own
    // so we provide help here
    foo() {}
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    A * = new C(); // all good
    A * = new D(); // error: cannot instantiate B<void>::foo
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve such an effect?

Comment: you may have some luck with sfinae.. have a look at std::enable_if (or boost::enable_if)

Comment: The other option is to provide a specialization of B<void>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SFINAE, you may do something like:

```
namespace detail
{
    // an helper for traits
    template <typename T>
    decltype(T{}, std::cout << T{}, std::true_type{})
    helper_has_default_constructor_and_foo(int);

    template <typename T>
    std::false_type helper_has_default_constructor_and_foo(...);

    // the traits
    template <typename T>
    using has_default_constructor_and_foo = decltype(helper_has_default_constructor_and_foo<T>(0));

    // genaral case (so when traits is false)
    template <typename T, typename = has_default_constructor_and_foo<T>>
    struct C : public A {};

    // specialization when traits is true
    template <typename T>
    struct C<T, std::true_type> : public A
    {
        void foo() override { std::cout << T{}; }
    };

}
```

And finally:

```
template <typename T>
class B : public detail::C<T>
{
};
```

[live demo](https://ideone.com/KkU0Tw)

Answer (score 0):

You could specialize for `B<void>`:

```
// template class
template <typename T>
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() 
    {
        T obj;
        std::cout << obj;
    }
};
template <>
class B<void> : public A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You **must** specialise `B<>` and cannot use SFINAE (on the member `foo`). SFINAE only works on templates, but member function templates cannot be `virtual`.

There are different ways you can achieve the specialization, but the most straightforward is the simple and explicit

```
template<typename T>
class B : public A
{
  /* ... */                // not overridden foo() by default
};

template<>
class B<WhatEver> : public A
{
  virtual foo();
};
```